# Javascript how can get attrs in below code

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3CcQ.png)

It returns undefined value when I try it as code.attrs or code["attrs"]
if you have any idea please feel free to let me know i've been working on this for hours.

```
[
  <ref *1> SoupTag {
    parent: SoupTag {
      parent: [SoupTag],
      previousElement: [SoupString],
      nextElement: [SoupString],
      name: 'div',
      contents: [Array],
      attrs: [Object],
      hidden: false,
      builder: [TreeBuilder]
    },
    previousElement: SoupString {
      parent: [SoupTag],
      previousElement: [SoupComment],
      nextElement: [Circular *1],
      _text: '     \n                    \n                    \n                    '
    },
    nextElement: SoupString {
      previousElement: [Circular *1],
      nextElement: [SoupComment],
      _text: '\n                    \n\n                    '
    },
    name: 'img',
    contents: [],
    attrs: {
      src: 'https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/750x422/4008038_0a54.jpg',
      alt: 'Sosyal Medya Pazarlaması, Reklamcılığı ve Yönetimi Eğitimi Coupon',
      class: 'card-img-top'
    },
    hidden: false,
    builder: TreeBuilder { EMPTY_ELEMENT_TAGS: [Set] }
  }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the snippet of damped data structure, the `code` is an array with one object. If you need `attr` property of this object, try `code[0].attrs`.